# Next.JS DatePicker / antd. How to disabled selected days?

Tags: date, next.js

How to disable selected days? I am assuming I can do it when past days are disable.
I am trying this solution, but it is not working. Thank you.

Code with disable past days, all is good:

```
const [val, setVal] = useState([])  
console.log(val)    // (2) ['14-06-2023', '17-06-2023']

const disabledDate = (current) => {
  const pastDays = current && current < dayjs().endOf('day')
  return pastDays
};

return (

<RangePicker 

         disabledDate={disabledDate} 

         onChange={val => {
          setVal(val.map(item => {
            return item.format('DD-MM-YYYY')
          }))
         }}/>
)
```

here is my solution, but it is not working and past days are not disable also. Something is wrong with it.

```
const disabledDate = (current) => {

  const selectedDays = val[0] >= dayjs().startOf('day') && 
                       val[1] <= dayjs().endOf('day')

  const pastDays = current && current < dayjs().endOf('day')
  return pastDays && selectedDays
};
```